# FAILED prompting authorization request to Heathkit

Tags: ios, healthkit

We are facing an issue in HealthKit permission dialog. it works in IOS 13 but it is not prompt in IOS 14.6. Please help me.

Below is the code

```
 func requestHealthKitAuthorization() {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let workoutType = HKObjectType.workoutType()
    let heartRateType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)
    let heartRateType1 = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)
    let heartRateType2 = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)
    let heartRateType3 = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)
    
    //reading
    let readingTypes = Set([heartRateType!,heartRateType1!,heartRateType2!,heartRateType3!, workoutType])
    //writing
    let writingTypes = Set([heartRateType!,heartRateType1!,heartRateType2!,heartRateType3!, workoutType])
    //auth request
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: writingTypes, read: readingTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
        
        if error != nil {
            print("error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else if success {
            print("success")
            //                    self.startButton.setEnabled(true)
        } else if !success {
            print("fail")
            
            //                    self.startButton.setEnabled(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart the device? Have you tried on real device?

Comment: yes, we are using real device.
Below are the errors.
[auth] FAILED prompting authorization request to share (
    HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning
), read (
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned,
    HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate,
    HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning
)
error Optional("Authorization session timed out")

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for answer, but probably entitlements are not correct. For some reason when u select capabilities from Xcode - it adds , it should be just a value.

instead of:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit.access</key>
<array/>
```

must be:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
<true/>
```

found this [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8430#issuecomment-617989390), thanks to [Matthew-Pitzer](https://github.com/Matthew-Pitzer)